# Extract customer date from magento with SQL statement - match up two different entity_ids

Tags: mysql, sql, magento

I am writing a small java application that when you input a customer ID and click lookup it should fetch details of that customer from a magento database. It is working as far as returning the ID, email, Firstname and Last Name but the address info (address, zip, county, country, phone) is not correct.  The reason is because the entity_id values in two different tables are mismatched.

The SQL query is :

```
SELECT
e.`entity_id` AS customer_id,
e.`email` ,
v1.`value` AS first_name,
v2.`value` AS last_name,
v10.`value` AS address,
v3.`value` AS zip,
v4.`value` AS city,
v6.`value` AS county,
v7.`value` AS country,
v5.`value` AS phone


FROM `ipw_customer_entity` e
INNER JOIN `ipw_customer_entity_varchar` v1 ON e.entity_id = v1.entity_id
INNER JOIN `ipw_customer_entity_varchar` v2 ON e.entity_id = v2.entity_id
INNER JOIN `ipw_customer_address_entity_varchar` v3 ON e.entity_id = v3.entity_id
INNER JOIN `ipw_customer_address_entity_varchar` v4 ON e.entity_id = v4.entity_id
INNER JOIN `ipw_customer_address_entity_varchar` v5 ON e.entity_id = v5.entity_id
INNER JOIN `ipw_customer_address_entity_varchar` v6 ON e.entity_id = v6.entity_id
INNER JOIN `ipw_customer_address_entity_varchar` v7 ON e.entity_id = v7.entity_id
INNER JOIN `ipw_customer_address_entity_text` v10 ON e.entity_id = v10.entity_id

WHERE
e.`entity_id` = 9 
AND v1.attribute_id = 5
AND v2.attribute_id = 7
AND v3.attribute_id = 30
AND v4.attribute_id = 26
AND v5.attribute_id = 31
AND v6.attribute_id = 28
AND v7.attribute_id = 27
AND v10.attribute_id = 25
```

N.B. e.entity.id=9  is just a value I have set it to for testing - the application passes the value input

I checked the tables in more detail and found that whilst the entity_id value in 'ipw_customer_entity' table is set to one value, for this example 9, the entity_id values in the tables 'ipw_customer_address_entity_text' and 'ipw_customer_address_entity_varchar' have a different value - for this record is 11.
There is a table 'ipw_customer_address_entity' that has a mapping of the two entity_ids though with the fields parent_id being equal to the 'ipw_customer_address_entity.entity_id'  and the field entity_id being equal to 'ipw_customer_address_entity_text.entity_id' and 'ipw_customer_address_entity_varchar.entity_id'

My question is , how can I change the SQL statement to account for this mapping and to make it works and return the correct address data for the first entity_id. That entity_value is also equal to the customer number on the magento admin so it makes sense to use that one as the input.

Comment: How are we supposed to know what the correct attribute IDs are in your database? 25 sounds like as good an option as any for "address" to me

Comment: How will you manage if a Customer has multiple addresses.

Comment: @scrowler - i checked the attribute IDs and they are correct for my installation - I know they can change. I didn't think they were actually relevant in regards to being able to answer the question though because the question is asking for help with the SQL statement to handle the mapping of the parent_id and the entity_id it maps to. If there is a problem with the attribute IDs thereafter then that is a separate issue and something I can remedy easily by changing them

Comment: @Red Devil - thats not something I though of thanks. Im 99% certain that none of my customer have multiple addresses in the 5 plus years I have been running the store, but it is a possibility. I will do a test to see what happens if I add one though (if it uses same attribute ID or a different one). I wouldn't actually need the second address though so if it just means it doesnt retrieve it then that is actually fine for me